# ms access - make a different report for each record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a ms access project, and I have there two tables, Maintain and subTable connected by key.
I have a lot of fields in each table.
I want to make a report that disappear fields with nulls differently for each record (I want to shrink textbox and tags and use their space, not only hide)
Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is not enough information to answer your question accurately. Please consider looking at [this (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further assistance.

Comment: Not sure what you want. Apply filter criteria so undesired records are not retrieved. Set textboxes with 0 Height, CanGrow Yes. Make the Detail section as small as possible. However, labels will not shrink/grow so they must be in different section, such as Page header.

Comment: I'll try to explain myself again.  I want to prepare a report that include supreport, both need to be printed in one page only. I have almost 120 different fields in those two tables, but most of them (75%) are not needed to be printed. Each record have a different fields with values and unnecessary fields (nulls,0 or -1), I want to have only those fields to be printed for each report. Do you have a way, thanks.

Comment: What kind of report is this - do you have multiple records on one page - or each page hosts a different record? What is in your subreport? You'd be much better explaining with a picture or pictures that match data

Comment: Each report have a lot of boolean fields (it's int with only 0,1) and each field like that have some fields of values. The sub report is the same, only that each ID from the report may have few different subreports. When the first field is 0, I don't want to print it and neither his values fields, but when a field have 1 i want to print his values (with labels of explain what is the number). It's a financial report, so I cant talk about the data, but you can understand that if some client have or doesn't have credit card then his data is different.